# React - Invalid Hook Call: convert App component to functional component, still get Invalid Hook Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

---

I have tried to create a simple app that allows a user to create or edit exiting 'projects'.

I am running in to the error:

react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

//
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:154234:5)
at App
//

The code for my 'App.js' is:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import MainPage from "./MainPage";
    //import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
    //<Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />;

    const App = () => {
      return (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/projects" element={<MainPage />} />
        </Routes>
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

Nothing renders in the browser but the console throws the above error. I thought the error was related to using a functional component, but that doesn't seem to fix it (or more likely I'm too daft to figure out what I've done wrong).

I originally had the following code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import MainPage from './MainPage';
    import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

    const App = () => (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path="/projects" component={MainPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );

    export default App;
```

I realised 'switch' needed to be replaced with 'routes' and based on other online documentation used the 'elements' prop instaed of the component prop.

```
import React from 'react';
 import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
 import MainPage from './MainPage';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

const App = () => {
 return (
     <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      <Route path="/projects" element={<MainPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
 };

export default App;`
```

Clearly this wan't the solution.

My MainPage.js code is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  DataTable,
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
} from 'carbon-components-react';

const MainPage = () => {
  // State for the list of projects
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  // Fetch the list of projects from the server when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/projects')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setProjects(data.projects));
  }, []);

  // Function to handle creating a new project
  const handleCreateProject = () => {
    // Display a form for the user to enter the project's name
        const projectName = window.prompt('Enter the name of the new project:');
       // If the user entered a name, create the new project and add it to the list
  if (projectName) {
    fetch('/api/projects', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ name: projectName }),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setProjects([...projects, data.project]));
  }
};

return (
  <div>
    <h1>My Projects</h1>
    <Button onClick={handleCreateProject}>Create New Project</Button>
    <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {projects.map((project) => (
            <TableRow key={project.id}>
              <TableCell>{project.name}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </div>
);
};

export default MainPage;
```

The LoginPage was just a placeholder (removed in the updated App.js).

My index.js code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

My package.json dependencies are:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Update:

Updated App.js now using RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter. This is now throwing a browser console error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

This seems to be coming from

return routes.map((route) => {

In the components.tsx file.

Current App.js code is:

```
    import React from "react";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import MainPage from "./MainPage";
//import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";

const router = createBrowserRouter();

const routes = [
  { path: "/projects", element: <MainPage /> },
  //{ path: '/login', element: <LoginPage /> },
  // add more routes here
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      <Routes>
        {routes.map((route) => (
          <Route path={route.path} element={route.element} />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </RouterProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please share your MainPage and LoginPage components

Comment: Added MainPage code - the LoginPage was just a placeholder, commented out in the App.js updated version

Comment: Nothing seems wrong so far. It could be that you are wrongly rendering the router. Post your index.js (Where you render your App component)

Comment: share your package.json dependencies list.

Comment: Added index.js
Added package.json dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path="/projects" component={MainPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

When you updated from `react-router-dom` v5 to v6, i.e. replace the `Switch` component with the `Routes` component and changed the `Route` props, you appear to have dropped the `Router` component. A router is still required.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      <Route path="/projects" element={<MainPage />} />
    </routes>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

You shared your project's dependencies but I don't see `react-router-dom` listed as a project dependency. Ensure `react-router-dom` is actually installed and that the package.json file lists it as a dependency.

```
npm install --save react-router-dom@6
```

If you are trying to use the newer RRDv6.4+ Data APIs then you specify all the routes in the `createBrowserRouter` function. In your example it's not passed an array of routes, so this seems to be the cause of the mapping error. Pass the `routes` configuration array to `createBrowserRouter`. The `RouterProvider` also takes no children, it's self-closed.

```
import React from "react";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import MainPage from "./MainPage";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";

// Routes configuration array
const routes = [
  { path: "/projects", element: <MainPage /> },
  { path: '/login', element: <LoginPage /> },
  // add more routes here
];

// Pass configuration array
const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest react-router-dom v6.4+ then you need to add   `RouterProvider` in your root file and create router configuration using `createBrowserRouter` .

Update your `index.js`

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import MainPage from "./MainPage";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <MainPage />
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <LoginPage />
  }
]);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Thanks Harsh - that has definitely changed things - I'm now getting an error: components.tsx:621 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at enhanceManualRouteObjects (components.tsx:621:1)
    
So will explore that now ....

Comment: Harsh - I think your answer was correct - however, I'm not understanding the error now being thrown which states that routes.map is undefined. I tried defining them upfront but the browser still throws and 'undefined' error. I've added my updated App.js to the main post.

Comment: I have added updates for index.js file. you can use something like this to configure your routes.